# How to edit a pandas_datetime object

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find indexes of events that are happening in a certain timeperiod. My time column in the Year/Month/Day Hour/Minute/Second format, e.g. '2014-06-30 17:35:00'

This can be done with this code:

```
start_date = '2014-06-30 17:35:00'
end_date = '2014-06-30 18:35:00'
data2.loc[(data2['event_timestamp'] > start_date) & (data2['event_timestamp'] < end_date)]
```

However, I need to pick a certain end date, subtract 1 hour, and define it as the "start_date" and can't seem to find out how.

So what needs to be done is:

```
For index, array in enumarate(df):
    if array[event] = positive:
    end_of_timewindow = array[timeframe of event]
    start_of_timewindow = #Here we need to subtract 1 hour of the ending_timewindow
    df.loc[(df['event_timestamp'] > start_timewindow) & (df['event_timestamp'] < end_timewindow)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some arithmetic with Timestamps and Timedelta objects, but it can be somewhat bothersome:

```py
start_date = '2014-06-30 17:35:00'
end_date = '2014-06-30 18:35:00'
new_enddate = pd.to_datetime(end_date) - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

You now have it as a pandas/numpy timestamp object, to get it back to a regular string you can do something like this:

```py
new_enddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Hope this is helpful to you.